# Change date in a data.frame based on matching string in a date vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Background**: I have a large data.frame consisting of values spanning from January 2021 until December 2021. However, the problem is that these dates do not match my dates in my SQL database. Thus, I have created a "ChangeDates" column which contains the "correct dates:

```
ChangeDates = c(
  "2021-01-29",
  "2021-02-26",
  "2021-03-31")
```

Furthermore, I have created a data.frame that consits of the dates that I want to change:

```
df_dates = data.frame(
  Date = c("2021-01-27", "2021-01-27","2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27",
           "2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27", "2021-01-27" ,
           "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27", "2021-01-27",
           "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27" ,"2021-01-27", "2021-01-27", "2021-01-27",
           "2021-01-27", "2021-02-27", "2021-02-27", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-27", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-27", "2021-02-27",
           "2021-02-27", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-27", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-27" ,"2021-03-29" ,"2021-03-29", "2021-03-29" ,"2021-03-29")
)
```

**Goal**: My goal is to somehow "dynamically" change all the "2021-01-27" dates to "2021-01-29", the  "2021-02-27" dates to "2021-02-26" and so on. So, the only manual thing I have to do is to adjust the dates in the "ChangeDates" vector and then the dates in df_dates are corrected as such.

I tried out with the "grepl" function. For example, if "2021-01" is found in df_dates and in ChangeDates, then change the cell value in df_dates to the value in ChangeDates.. However, it seems that I have a bit of trouble in doing so..

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a table of "from" and "to" dates, and check that it is accurate.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

change_table <- tibble(from = unique(df_dates$Date), to = ChangeDates)
change_table
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   from       to        
#>   <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 2021-01-27 2021-01-29
#> 2 2021-02-27 2021-02-26
#> 3 2021-03-29 2021-03-31
```

If so, join this to your data frame and `coalesce` the `to` with your `Date` variable.

```r
df_dates %>% 
  left_join(change_table, by = c('Date' = 'from')) %>% 
  mutate(Date = coalesce(to, Date), 
         to = NULL)
#>          Date
#> 1  2021-01-29
#> 2  2021-01-29
#> 3  2021-01-29
#> 4  2021-01-29
#> 5  2021-01-29
#> 6  2021-01-29
#> 7  2021-01-29
#> 8  2021-01-29
#> 9  2021-01-29
#> 10 2021-01-29
#> 11 2021-01-29
#> 12 2021-01-29
#> 13 2021-01-29
#> 14 2021-01-29
#> 15 2021-01-29
#> 16 2021-01-29
#> 17 2021-01-29
#> 18 2021-01-29
#> 19 2021-01-29
#> 20 2021-01-29
#> 21 2021-01-29
#> 22 2021-01-29
#> 23 2021-01-29
#> 24 2021-01-29
#> 25 2021-01-29
#> 26 2021-01-29
#> 27 2021-01-29
#> 28 2021-01-29
#> 29 2021-01-29
#> 30 2021-01-29
#> 31 2021-01-29
#> 32 2021-02-26
#> 33 2021-02-26
#> 34 2021-02-26
#> 35 2021-02-26
#> 36 2021-02-26
#> 37 2021-02-26
#> 38 2021-02-26
#> 39 2021-02-26
#> 40 2021-02-26
#> 41 2021-02-26
#> 42 2021-02-26
#> 43 2021-02-26
#> 44 2021-02-26
#> 45 2021-03-31
#> 46 2021-03-31
#> 47 2021-03-31
#> 48 2021-03-31
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be creating another vector which indicates the current values in the df that you want to replace with the ones in the ChangeDates vector.

```
FromDates = c("2021-01-27",
              "2021-02-27",
              "2021-03-29")
```

Then look for the position in that vector that matches the respective current values in the df, feeding a new df with the values in the vector matching that same position.

```
new.df_dates <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:dim(df_dates)[1]){

  new.df_dates[i,1] <- ChangeDates[which(FromDates==df_dates$Date[i])]
  
}

colnames(new.df_dates) <- colnames(df_dates)
```

With this, you'd get:

```
head(new.df_dates)
        Date
1 2021-01-29
2 2021-01-29
3 2021-01-29
4 2021-01-29
5 2021-01-29
6 2021-01-29

tail(new.df_dates)
         Date
43 2021-02-26
44 2021-02-26
45 2021-03-31
46 2021-03-31
47 2021-03-31
48 2021-03-31
```